# Nesting a SELECT-WHERE query within an INSERT-WHERE query in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have created a select -where subquery inside an insert query but no updates are visible in my database.

I need to first select a value from the database and then pass that selected value from the database and then pass that selected value in another query to get another value from mysql database.

Here is my Sample Code

```
 <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpSession" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpSession" %>
<%@page import="com.dbutil.CrudOperation"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullview.css">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Job Details</title>
    </head>

    <body>

       <% Connection con = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            HttpSession hs = null;
            con = CrudOperation.createConnection();
            hs = request.getSession();
           String value=request.getParameter("idJob");
            String id = (String) hs.getAttribute("userinfo");
            %>
            <div class="container">



                 <%String strsql = "select name from register where uname=?"; 
                try
        {
            ps=con.prepareStatement(strsql);
            ps.setString(1, id);


            int rw1=ps.executeUpdate();


                if(rw1>0) {

                                con.commit();
                    String tryname=rs.getString("name");
                   String strsql1 = "insert into postjob1(applicants) values(?) where id=?"; 
                try
        {
            ps=con.prepareStatement(strsql1);
            ps.setString(1, tryname);
                        ps.setString(2,value);


            rs=ps.executeQuery();


                if(rs.next()) {
                    con.commit();
                    response.sendRedirect("confirm.jsp");


                }
                else{
                 response.sendRedirect("Oops.jsp");}

            }
            catch(SQLException se)
                {
                    System.out.println(se);
                }



                }
                else{
                response.sendRedirect("Oops1.jsp");}             
            }
            catch(SQLException se)
                {
                    System.out.println(se);
                }



   %>
                %>



            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **not** put SQL code in JSP pages. Create a servlet or a custom JSP tag for that.

Answer (score 0):

Insert statement creates new record in the table, and doesn't have a where clause. So, you have a syntax error in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There's is a Syntax error in your SQL Statement.

```
String strsql1 = "insert into postjob1(applicants) values(?) where id=?";
```

INSERT INTO cannot contain WHERE clause.
If yo want to Update a existing record in a table use UPDATE table statement instead. Your query will be like

`String strsql1 =UPDATE [Yourtable] SET [Tablecolumn] = '[updated-value]' WHERE [Tablecolumn] = [ExistingValue];`